# Will the center of one be larger than the center of the other?(center of gravity)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, finance

Assume that you have $n$ positive values $C_1,C_2,\ldots,C_n$, and you have $n$ values $g_1,g_2,\ldots,g_n$ where each $g_t\in[0,0.1]$.

Do we then have that

$$\frac{\sum\limits_{t=1}^n\frac{C_tg_t}{(1+g_t)^t}}{\sum\limits_{t=1}^n\frac{C_t}{(1+g_t)^t}}\ge\frac{\sum\limits_{t=2}^n\frac{C_tg_t}{(1+g_t)^{t-1}}}{\sum\limits_{t=2}^n\frac{C_t}{(1+g_t)^{t-1}}}?$$

Comment: Seems unlikely to be true in general. There’s no other information about the $g$ or $C$?

Comment: @user7530 No, this is the information available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a counterexample, if
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{align*}
&n=2\\[4pt]
&C_1=C_2=1\\[4pt]
&g_1,g_2=\frac{1}{20},\frac{1}{10}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
then letting $L,R$ denote respectively the $\text{LHS},\text{RHS}$ of your proposed inequality, we get
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{align*}
R&=\frac{1}{10}\\[4pt]
L&=\frac{331}{4520}\\[4pt]
R-L&=\frac{121}{4520}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
so $R > L$.

In fact, for the case $n=2$, your proposed inequality holds if and only if $g_1 \ge g_2$.